# Как назвать документ именем переменной?

Tags: python

У меня есть переменная word, в которую записывается значение, введенное пользователем - это строка из букв.
Далее я хочу создать файл, который будет называться значением переменной word.
Например, если введено 'abc' файл должен называться 'abc.txt'
Возможно ли это сделать?

Comment: что именно не получается?

Comment: назвать файл получается только word.txt

Comment: я не могу запихнуть значение переменной в название

Answer (score 2):

```
word=input()
with open(word,'w') as file: #если with open('word'... то есть в кавычках то будет создан файл word, если без кавычек то будет создан файл со значением переменной word
  file.write('something becourse value is name')
#or
import os
os.system(f'touch {word}')
```

Comment: спасибо большое! я рассмотрела все варианты, кроме самого очевидного

Answer (score 2):

Можно  сделать гораздо легче, чем сделал **@ganz**

```
word=input()
test=open(f'{word}.txt', 'w')
test.write(f'No text. This is file {word}.txt')
test.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

`word` нужно писать без кавычек.

Comment: И добавить `+` после `word` :)