# Название файла из значения переменной

Tags: python, tkinter

Ночи! В связи с расширением функционала приложения появилась необходимость сохранять результат работы программы в небольшой текстовый отчет, для чего использую такую функцию:

```
def save_report():
    filepath = asksaveasfilename(
        defaultextension="txt",
        filetypes=[("Текстовые файлы", "*.txt"), ("HTML файлы", "*.html")]
    )
    if not filepath:
        return
    with open(filepath, "w", encoding="UTF-8") as output_file:
        pt_name = patientName_entry.get()
        pt_date = patientDate_entry.get()
        pt_sex = patientSelectSex.get()

        vl_manifestation = manifestationSelect.get()
        vl_hearth = hearthSelect.get()
        vl_transformation = transformationSelect.get()
        vl_deficit = deficitSelect.get()
        vl_infarct = infarctSelect.get()
        vl_thrombolysis = thrombolysisSelect.get()

        vl_conclusion = conclusion.cget("text")

        locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '')
        report_date = datetime.now()
        report_date = report_date.strftime('%d %B %Y')

        text_report = (
            f'Assessing the risk of surgical intervention in stroke (ARSiS) report.\n'
            f'=====================================================================\n'
            f'отчет сформирован: {report_date}\n\n'
            f'ПАЦИЕНТ:\n{pt_name}\n'
            f'Дата рождения: {pt_date}\n'
            f'Пол: {pt_sex}\n'
            f'---------------------------------------------------------------------\n\n'
            f'АНАМНЕЗ / ДАННЫЕ ИССЛЕДОВАНИЙ:\n'
            f'1. Время с момента манифестации первых симптомов неврологического дефицита:\n'
            f'   -> {vl_manifestation}\n\n'
            f'2. Очаг ишемического инсульта в любом из диаметров, по данным КТ или МРТ головного мозга:\n'
            f'   -> {vl_hearth}\n\n'
            f'3. Геморрагическая трансформация ишемического очага в головном мозге:\n'
            f'   -> {vl_transformation}\n\n'
            f'4. Неврологический дефицит:\n'
            f'   -> {vl_deficit}\n\n'
            f'5. Острый инфаркт миокарда:\n'
            f'   -> {vl_infarct}\n\n'
            f'6. Состояние после тромболитической терапии:\n'
            f'   -> {vl_thrombolysis}\n'
            f'---------------------------------------------------------------------\n\n'
            f'ЗАКЛЮЧЕНИЕ:\n'
            f'{vl_conclusion}'
        )
        output_file.write(text_report)
```

Все прекрасно работает, но я хотел бы что бы при сохранении в файл, название автоматически формировалось из значений переменных `patientName_entry` и `patientDate_entry`. Сами переменные это текстовые поля, куда пользователь вручную вводит данные. Должно получится как-то так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но как такое реализовать не понимаю. В качестве ориентира использовал материал этого [вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1357938/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82-%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Благодаря ответу Stanislav Volodarskiy, удалось добиться поставленной цели. Ниже работающая функция. Может кому-то пригодится.

```
def save_report():
    pt_name = patientName_entry.get()
    pt_date = patientDate_entry.get()
    pt_sex = patientSelectSex.get()

    vl_manifestation = manifestationSelect.get()
    vl_hearth = hearthSelect.get()
    vl_transformation = transformationSelect.get()
    vl_deficit = deficitSelect.get()
    vl_infarct = infarctSelect.get()
    vl_thrombolysis = thrombolysisSelect.get()

    vl_conclusion = conclusion.cget("text")

    locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '')
    report_date = datetime.now()
    report_date = report_date.strftime('%d %B %Y')

    filepath = asksaveasfilename(
        defaultextension="txt",
        filetypes=[("Текстовые файлы", "*.txt"), ("HTML файлы", "*.html")],
        initialfile=f'{pt_name} {pt_date}.txt'
    )

    if not filepath:
        return
    with open(filepath, "w", encoding="UTF-8") as output_file:

        text_report = (
            f'Assessing the risk of surgical intervention in stroke (ARSiS) report.\n'
            f'=====================================================================\n'
            f'отчет сформирован: {report_date}\n\n'
            f'ПАЦИЕНТ:\n{pt_name}\n'
            f'Дата рождения: {pt_date}\n'
            f'Пол: {pt_sex}\n'
            f'---------------------------------------------------------------------\n\n'
            f'АНАМНЕЗ / ДАННЫЕ ИССЛЕДОВАНИЙ:\n'
            f'1. Время с момента манифестации первых симптомов неврологического дефицита:\n'
            f'   -> {vl_manifestation}\n\n'
            f'2. Очаг ишемического инсульта в любом из диаметров, по данным КТ или МРТ головного мозга:\n'
            f'   -> {vl_hearth}\n\n'
            f'3. Геморрагическая трансформация ишемического очага в головном мозге:\n'
            f'   -> {vl_transformation}\n\n'
            f'4. Неврологический дефицит:\n'
            f'   -> {vl_deficit}\n\n'
            f'5. Острый инфаркт миокарда:\n'
            f'   -> {vl_infarct}\n\n'
            f'6. Состояние после тромболитической терапии:\n'
            f'   -> {vl_thrombolysis}\n'
            f'---------------------------------------------------------------------\n\n'
            f'ЗАКЛЮЧЕНИЕ:\n'
            f'{vl_conclusion}'
        )
        output_file.write(text_report)
```

Answer (score 1):

Обратите внимание на `initialfile=` и `initialdir=` в [Native Load/Save Dialogs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dialog.html#native-load-save-dialogs):

```
from tkinter.filedialog import asksaveasfilename


patientName_entry = "Иванов Иван Иванович"
patientDate_entry = "12.12.1980"

f = asksaveasfilename(
    defaultextension="txt",
    filetypes=[("Текстовые файлы", "*.txt"), ("HTML файлы", "*.html")],
    initialfile=f'{patientName_entry} {patientDate_entry}.txt'
)

print(repr(f))
```

Comment: Спасибо! Попробую, отпишусь!

Comment: Все работает благодаря совету Stanislav Volodarskiy! Спасибо!